# Java Compilation Speed

Tags: java, maven, compilation, javac, xjc

I have a Java project with ~2400 classes.  They are mostly generated using XJC from XML schema with a few extensions.

Compilation takes very long time, ~20 minutes, and I was wondering if there's anything I can do to improve this?

A similar project has around half the number of generated classes, but several hand-written classes instead, for a total of ~3000 classes.  This compiles in a more stomachable 2-5 minutes.

I am using Java 8 (1.8.0_92 on Windows) for compilation, but using source and target version 6 (so the issue is not the slow type system on Java 8).  Compilation is done using Maven 3.3.3 using maven-compiler-plugin 3.5.1.  I am forking the compiler off Maven and  use maxmem 2048m.

The generated classes are generally small, but I have one huge visitor touching all the generated classes (so there's a one to all and an all to one dependency).  I cannot really do anything about this.

Switching from "mvn clean install" to "mvn install" (or just "mvn compile") helps, but this is not always an option (basically, Eclipse screws around with compiled files, so to be sure tests run ok, I need to clean while running tests from the command like before committing).

I don't have any background processes watching the compilation unit files (like Eclipse/SourceTree), but I do have a virus scanner (which I cannot switch off).  It seems most of the time is spent by javac.

Is there something in javac that is super-linear in the number of mutually dependent classes?  Or is there a way I can get around these compilation times?

**E**: I got a suggestion for running Maven multi-threaded; unfortunately I've already tried this, and it doesn't really help here as it's a single-module project with a lot of interdependent classes.

**E2**: I split the project into a module with just the JAXB code and another with the main code.  Turns out, the JAXB code wasn't the culprit.  I ran the [Tesla Maven Profiler](https://github.com/takari/maven-profiler) and it just confirmed the compilation is the issue; relevant part:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 (default-compile) 18m 48s
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 (default-testCompile) 14s 770ms
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 (default-test) 1m 51s
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.0.1 (default-war) 14s 635ms
```

I'm perfectly fine with the duration of the last three.

This is just 1000 Java classes, all inheriting from a common visitor generated using JAXB.  My compile configuration:

```
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>         
                          <fork>true</compiler>
                          <source>${compileSource}</source>
                          <target>${compileSource}</target>
                          <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
                          <maxmem>2048m</mexmem>
                          <encoding>UTF-8<eencoding>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
```

(compileSource is 1.6)

Comment: Re "Eclipse screws around with compiled files": To avoid conflicts between maven and Eclipse much can be improved by selectively enabling / disabling "Build automatically" in Eclipse: make sure only one tool at a time works on your projects. After maven has run don't forget to refresh resources in Eclipse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out, the issues is really in javac.  Javac cannot handle classes with wildly overloaded methods very well (http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2013-May/006339.html).

I was generating a visitor, which generated a visit(...) method for each class (1100+), causing compilation of each derivative to take several seconds.  As I had hundreds of these methods, this all added up.

My visitor was generated using jaxb-visitor (https://github.com/massfords/jaxb-visitor) and fixed the issue by including the typename in generated methods using my own fork of the code (https://github.com/klafbang/jaxb-visitor).

Compilation time went down (from 40 minutes) to 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

A way to solve your problem, could be to split your maven project and create one only for generated classes, this one does not need to be rebuild every time, only when xsd changes. And get it be dependency in the other project.

Comment: Sometimes, you overlook the simplest solutions... Thanks for the suggestion!  Will try that and get back about whether it solves the problem.

Comment: This - after a lot of refactoring - unfortunately didn't resolve the issue.  My JAXB code now compiles in "only" 3-4 minutes while my application code takes most of the time (20-25 minutes).

Comment: You can launch maven in a console with -e to log the detail and maybe you will see where it spend most of time. With this hint you'll be able to split the project to compile only the part that you need.

Comment: That didn't really give anything new.  I switched on the Tesla Maven profiler [link](https://github.com/takari/maven-profiler), which provided a bit more information, but nothing new:  time is spent compiling the main module.

The new JAXB module is a couple minutes and won't recompile often, so that's ok.

The main module spends time compiling (and testing but that's acceptable).  I'm trying to make javac give compilation statistics but my Google-fu doesn't seem to suffice...

Comment: I added the output from the profiler + my javac configuration to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Multithread option introduced since 3, not sure, how it can improve in your case since you have single module, might be your test runs be bit faster, but you can check though with this option

```
mvn clean install -T5C
```

Here is the [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) explaining the parallel build

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I forgot to mention, I've already attempted a multi-threaded build - I'll edit my question.

Unfortunately, as you also suspect, it doesn't really help here as the problem really is with the compilation of the 2400 interdependent classes.